# Menu being cropped

Tags: menu, mfc

I have a MFC project. It supports over 40 languages.

On my PC I have two monitors. They are both different size monitors and different resolutions.

If I move my application onto the smaller monitor the complete language menu does not display. I understood it would show scroll bars. Why isn't it?

My menu is a standard menu. Nothing fancy.

My main monitor has higher resolution and I can see full menu.

Please advise.

Thanks.
[image: Menu]

Comment: I assume your program is "per monitor dpi aware" as opposed to "dpi aware"?

Comment: I don’t know is the honest answer. How do I examine that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to set DPI awareness. It depends how you have set this value.

Click `"Project Properties"` -> `"Manifest Tools"` -> `"DPI Awareness"`

It might say `"High DPI Aware"` in your case, that could explain the problem. Change it to `"Per Monitor High DPI Aware"`

[image]

---

Or you can set this value in manifest file, in dpiAware section, in this manifest file the value should be `"True/PM"` instead of `"True"`. The manifest file will be names `"myapp.exe.manifest"` it should be in resource directory.

```
<dpiAware>True/PM</dpiAware>
```

In your case the value might be `"True"`, that could explain the problem.

---

Or you might be using [`SetProcessDpiAwareness`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302122(v=vs.85).aspx). In that case it should use the value `PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE`.

It's also possible that you are using `SetProcessDPIAware`! This function is deprecated.

See also 
[Creating a DPI-Aware Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681(v=vs.85).aspx)
[High DPI Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447398(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much. My settings were set to **High DPI Aware**. I adjusted it to the other setting and the menu displays properly on both monitors. Thank you. :)