# The dialog size is different in computers

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have one desktop and one laptop (windows 10).
The size of the monitor installed on the desktop is 24 inches.

They are same resolution(1920 by 1080) and i set same zoom ratio in Windows 10.

I do not use Movewindow function or other things to fix the size, however, the dialog size in the laptop and the desktop is different.
It causes that the controls in my software are overlapping each other.

please let me know if i notify other settings!!

Thank you.

---

Sorry, my question is not specific, i add two pictures.

In laptop, the setting of Windows is overlapped with the setting of DICOM.
Of course, i can make the controls not overlapping when i directly use 'movewindow' on dialog, but i want to know why the two dialogs have different size.(same resolution(1920 x 1080), same zoom ratio on windows 10)
In Desktop, the print dialog has 791 x 632 size, in latop, the print dialog has 911 x 816 size.

I will check DPI-Awareness. Thank you for your comments!

[image]

---

I'm getting to know about this phenomenon.
In laptop, The resolution is 1920 X 1080, However, the ratio value which Windows 10 recommend is 125%.
I Change the ratio to 100% then, It worked at a higher resolution i think.

[image]
I use this code to get a resoltion.

`MONITORINFO mi;
::ZeroMemory(&mi, sizeof MONITORINFO );
mi.cbSize = sizeof MONITORINFO;`

`if( ::GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &mi))`

In laptop,
When i use 100% the size of text, apps, and other items in Scale and layout,
then The mi.rcMonitor's width = 2400
if i change the ratio value to 125%(which windows recommend), then The mi.rcMonitor's width = 1920

I don't know how to represent 2400 * 1350 in 1920 * 1080 monitor, so i will study this!

Comment: Is your application [DPI aware](http://stackoverflow.com/a/47647122/4603670)? Show screen shot of your dialog to make it clear what the problem is.

Comment: What do you mean with "dialog size is different"? Measured in pixels or in dialog units or in centimeters? Can you provide a screen capture of the good and the bad display?

Comment: Please include [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your comments, and Sorry i am not good at English, so i can show meaning that i do not intend. My question is not specific, so i include a picture!!