# Position the window on larger monitor

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I work on extra 21" monitor with laptops. When I click [TightVNC viewer](https://www.tightvnc.com/download.php) icon in the task bar it usually opens on the smaller laptop screen. Then I'd have to drag it to the larger monitor to work.

I've zeroed on the code which we can change to automatically move the TightVNC viewer to the larger display if available.

The existing code:

```
void CentreWindow(HWND hwnd)
{
    RECT winrect, workrect;

    // Find how large the desktop work area is
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, &workrect, 0);
    int workwidth = workrect.right -  workrect.left;
    int workheight = workrect.bottom - workrect.top;

    // And how big the window is
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &winrect);
    int winwidth = winrect.right - winrect.left;
    int winheight = winrect.bottom - winrect.top;
    // Make sure it's not bigger than the work area
    winwidth = min(winwidth, workwidth);
    winheight = min(winheight, workheight);

    // Now centre it
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, 
        HWND_TOP,
        workrect.left + (workwidth-winwidth) / 2,
        workrect.top + (workheight-winheight) / 2,
        winwidth, winheight, 
        SWP_SHOWWINDOW);  
    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
}
```

I guess, firstly I need to inquire total displays and find the largest display then position the window in the center of it.
**Can anybody tell me reference code using which I can build this logic**?

Comment: Make sure your program is DPI aware, [see link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47647122/4603670). In MFC, you can use `wnd->CenterWindow()`, this will also deal with multi-monitor setup. Add `WinAPI` tag if this is not MFC question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to decide which display you want it on. This requires enumerating the available displays, which will give you access to their properties. From that, you decide what algorithm you want to use to select a display—which one is largest, which one supports the most colors, which one is furthest to the left in the [virtual screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/the-virtual-screen), etc.

Enumerating the available displays is straightforward using the [`EnumDisplayMonitors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors) Windows API function, but does require a fair amount of code. Here is a tested and fully working implementation:

```
struct MonitorInfo
{
   HMONITOR hMonitor;
   RECT     rcMonitor;

   MonitorInfo(HMONITOR hMonitor, RECT rcMonitor)
      : hMonitor (hMonitor)
      , rcMonitor(rcMonitor)
   { }
};

BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor,
                              HDC   /* hdcMonitor */,
                              RECT*    prcMonitor,
                              LPARAM   dwData)
{
   ASSERT(hMonitor   != NULL);
   ASSERT(prcMonitor != nullptr);
   ASSERT(dwData     != NULL);

   MONITORINFO mi;
   mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
   VERIFY(::GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &mi));

   if ((mi.dwFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER) == DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER)
   {
      // Skip mirroring drivers that do not correspond to display screens.
      return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
      auto* const pInfo = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<MonitorInfo>*>(dwData);
      ASSERT(pInfo != nullptr);

      pInfo->emplace_back(hMonitor, *prcMonitor);

      return TRUE;
   }
}

std::vector<MonitorInfo> GetInfoForAllMonitors()
{
   const int cMonitors = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS);

   std::vector<MonitorInfo> result;
   result.reserve(cMonitors);

   ::EnumDisplayMonitors(nullptr,
                         nullptr,
                         MonitorEnumProc,
                         reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&result));

   ASSERT(result.size() > 0);
   ASSERT(result.size() == cMonitors);

   return result;
}
```

This returns a `std::vector` of `MonitorInfo` objects. The `MonitorInfo` objects contain a rectangle describing the monitor's display area, and a handle to the monitor (`HMONITOR`), which you can use to get additional information.

For example, you can pass an `HMONITOR` to the [`GetMonitorInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfow) function. It will fill in a [`MONITORINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagmonitorinfo), or [`MONITORINFOEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagmonitorinfoexw) structure. This will give you the working area as a rectangle, and indicate whether the monitor is the primary monitor in the system.

By way of example, here is how I use it:

```
const auto  monitors = GetInfoForAllMonitors();
const auto rcMonitor = monitors[g_App.m_settings.Screen].rcMonitor;
this->SetWindowPos(nullptr,
                   rcMonitor.left, rcMonitor.top,
                   rcMonitor.Width(), rcMonitor.Height(),
                   SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOREDRAW);
```

That's located in the `OnInitDialog` function for the dialog box whose position I want to adjust. In this case, it fills the entire monitor's screen area (not just the working area, so it would, for example, cover the taskbar). Which monitor to use is configured by the user in a preference file, and stored in the global variable `g_App.m_settings.Screen`. You could just as easily replace that with logic to use whichever monitor's working area is largest.